# Azure: programmatically querying WADLogsTable for trace data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to use the following code to get all trace data for the last hour from Azure:

```
                StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey storageCredentialsAccountAndKey = new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(accountName, key);
                CloudStorageAccount csa = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentialsAccountAndKey, true);
                TableServiceContext tableServiceContext = new TableServiceContext(csa.TableEndpoint.ToString(), csa.Credentials);
                var results = tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<TableServiceEntity>("WADLogsTable").Where(
                    x => x.Timestamp > DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1)).ToList();
```

However, I'm finding that no results are found when I know that there is data in the table for the last hour (I'm comparing the output to Cerebrata's Azure Diagnostics Manager).

I have two questions:

1. Is this the right way to query WADLogsTable? Why am I not seeing any
   results?
2. What is the correct type to pass in as the generic
   parameter? `TableServiceEntity` is a base class that only defines
   three columns. I'd like to know if there is a type that represents a
   WADLogsTable entity specifically. Do I just create a type with
   properties the same as the column names?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no out of the box type (class) that would represent WADLogs entity. Using the base class you will only get the PartionKey, RowKey and Timestamp properties. You have to define it by yourself. Here a sample that I use:

```
public class WadLogEntity
       : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceEntity
    {
        public WadLogEntity()
        {
            PartitionKey = "a";
            RowKey = string.Format("{0:10}_{1}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks, Guid.NewGuid());
        }

        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string RoleInstance { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int Pid { get; set; }
        public int Tid { get; set; }
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public DateTime EventDateTime
        {
            get
            {
                return new DateTime(long.Parse(this.PartitionKey.Substring(1)));
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, when I was struggling with the WADLogs table, I managed to get it showing the results (for the last 24 hours) with this code:

```
  var dtThen = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-24);
                var dtNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

                var logs = this._wadLogs.WadLogs.Where(
                    wl => 
                        wl.Level == 2 
                        && String.Compare(wl.PartitionKey,"0" + dtThen.Ticks.ToString()) >=0
                        && String.Compare(wl.PartitionKey, "0" + dtNow.Ticks.ToString()) < 0
                    ).Take(200);
```

I noted that there is a "0" prefix in the partition key before the ticks count.

Comment: Thank you Anton. What is the type of `this` in your second snippet?

Comment: It's okay, I've worked out it's an `IQueryable<WadLogEntity>`.

Comment: Thanks, I've got this working now. The reason it didn't work before was because, for some excruciating reason, you can't query against the `Timestamp` column. Top marks to you, Anton.

Comment: Great that it works for you now. And yes, you are generally not advised to use the Timestamp column. It is for internal use only.

Comment: There's a '0' before the ticks because the ticks might get over the 0999999999900000000 mark at some point. A safer way is to use String.Format("{0:0000000000000000000}", ticks)... although that would be at November 16th... in 3169... I don't think I'll live by then :)

Comment: Might be helpful to note that `this.wadLogs.WadLogs` is `tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<TableServiceEntity>("WADLogsTable")` from the question

Comment: As is common with microsoft, the class you use in your example is now deprecated.  Just thought i'd leave a note for other people like me trying to figure this junk out.

Comment: Appreciate your comment. Although the class is depricated, the approach and logic has not been changed.

Comment: There are lots of time columns: `PartitionKey` `Timestamp`, `TIMESTAMP`, `PreciseTimeStamp`. [Use the last in your query results, it's more useful. the others are related to the time the events were batchinserted into `WADLogsTable`, not the time the event happened.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-diagnostics-for-cloud-services-and-virtual-machines/)

Answer (score -1):

For users of the latest (2014) Azure Storage client:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2014/02/11/how-to-view-azure-diagnostics-traces-from-wadlogstable-in-your-local-console-app.aspx

**tl;dr** you *can* use Timestamp for filtering.

```
...
var query = table.CreateQuery<GenericTableEntity>()
    .Where(e => e.Timestamp > DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-120));
```

By extending the entity in the linked example, you can expose the Message and Date variables:

```
public class LogEntity : GenericTableEntity 
{
    // Since Timestamp is a DateTimeOffset
    public DateTime LogDate
    {
        get { return Timestamp.UtcDateTime; }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return Properties["Message"].StringValue; }
    }
}
```